K3s dont want to place pods on master node to deploy Minecraft server
I run a k3s kluster on 2 raspberry pis (1 rasp5 and 1 rasp4) and want to place pods on both nodes(and place a loadbalancer on this bad boy). It is a minecraft server i want to deploy.
This is my deployment file:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: minecraft-server
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: minecraft-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: minecraft-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: minecraft
          image: itzg/minecraft-server:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 25565
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "500m"
              memory: "1Gi"
          env:
            - name: EULA
              value: "TRUE"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: minecraft-data
              mountPath: "/data"
            - name: kube-api-access
              mountPath: "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"
      volumes:
        - name: minecraft-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: minecraft-data-pvc
        - name: kube-api-access
          projected:
            sources:
              - configMap:
                  name: kube-root-ca.crt
                  items:
                    - key: ca.crt
                      path: kube-root-ca.crt
              - serviceAccountToken:
                  path: token
                  expirationSeconds: 3607
      nodeSelector: {}
      tolerations:
        - key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
          operator: Exists
          effect: NoExecute
          tolerationSeconds: 300
        - key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
          operator: Exists
          effect: NoExecute
          tolerationSeconds: 300

I get "pending" on the pods if I try force nodeSelector to choose the master node (Raspberry Pi):
kubernetes.io/hostname: raspberrypi

If I open the logs of the pods that are "pending" it says:

Warning FailedScheduling 13m default-scheduler 0/2 nodes are
available: 1 node is filtered out by the prefilter result, 1 node(s)
didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. preemption: 0/2 nodes are
available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling. Warning
FailedScheduling 2m56s (x2 over 7m56s) default-scheduler 0/2 nodes are
available: 1 node is filtered out by the prefilter result, 1 node(s)
didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. preemption: 0/2 nodes are
available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.

I've tried to drain the pods, restarting the cluster, see if the memory or CPU is overloaded.
Labels for the nodes:
kubectl get nodes --show-labels
NAME          STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION        LABELS
smeagol       Ready    <none>                 23h   v1.29.5+k3s1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=arm64,beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=k3s,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=arm64,kubernetes.io/hostname=smeagol,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=k3s
raspberrypi   Ready    control-plane,master   23h   v1.29.5+k3s1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=arm64,beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=k3s,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=arm64,kubernetes.io/hostname=raspberrypi,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane=true,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=k3s


I don't know if k3s is similar in this behaviour, but in k8s you need to label the node. Use kubectl label node rasp5 node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker

I added some info in the post. I should have labeled the nodes already?

None of them have the worker role, you have two lazy pi's refusing to work.
